# Cannot establish connection between Xdebug Client and Server

Tags: php, linux, xdebug

I am trying to execute `xdebug` using `dbgp` client but I cannot establish a connection with the server.

My phpinfo:

```
xdebug.remote_enable    On  
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   
xdebug.remote_mode  req 
xdebug.remote_port  9001
```

I run the client first:

```
[/usr/local/bin]# ./debugclient
 Xdebug Simple DBGp client (0.10.0)
 Copyright 2002-2007 by Derick Rethans.
 - libedit support: enabled

 Waiting for debug server to connect.
```

I run the script:

```
# export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug"
# php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 debug_tmp.php
```

Check the stat:

```
# netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign   Address             State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2082                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2083                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2086                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2087                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2095                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2096                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 69.174.52.164:22            111.94.64.239:7531          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     64 69.174.52.164:22            111.94.64.239:1698          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:31750             127.0.0.1:80                TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 :::21                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::25                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::993                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::995                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::3306                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::587                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::110                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::143                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::465                      :::*                        LISTEN
```

But still, connection is not established.

```
Log opened at 2015-01-28 12:22:03
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2015-01-28 12:22:03
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,
the client is set to 9000 for some reason. So I set the xdebug port to 9000, now it's working